# how to make a data manipulation language like SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-design

How to make a data manipulation language like SQL, and implement the basic functions like

```
insert, join, natural join
```

I tried to search online, but I didn't get any proper link, where I can start from. Most of the results go towards making a SQL parser.

So I wanted to ask

1. What is the basic idea behind making a DML?
2. How should I be manipulating the data?
3. Which language or platform should I be using to implement it?

If possible, please post any links of past works in this field.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I hate when people downvote these type of questions. Since when is learning a bad thing?

Comment: Take a look at Rel also Rel359

Comment: Well, you'll first have to make a DBMS before you can make a query language for it.

Comment: I think this would make a good open ended interview question. Especially if you then asked how you'd make it transactional.

Comment: There's a book by Hector Garcia-Molina on the subject of DBMS building, and focussed on SQL as the query language (not exactly the best of ideas any more these days, but never mind).  Might be out of print, though.

Answer (score 2):

The search terms you're looking for are [`relational algebra`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) and [`relational calculus`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_relational_calculus). I'd rather not go into too much detail, since this usually takes about 6 weeks to cover in a college databases course.

The basic idea is that SQL is a "relational calculus" in that it describes the result you'd like to achieve. It is the job of the DBMS to compile this into a "relational algebra," which describes how to analyze the data.

Answer (score 2):

Ref points 1 and 2 of your question:

I would start off by reading up about some of the theory behind SQL. Chris Date's books (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date) are a good place to start.

Point 3.

Presumably you'll have to learn this language. I'd pick something modern with nice high level constructs, and built in String manipulation, Ruby, Python, C# or, Java?

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to implement all the functions to do basic operations such as projection, filtering, joining, indexing... Once this functionality is in place, you need to parse SQL, create a queryvexecution plan that will then call your API to get the results. This is of course a very crude description. I would suggest to read open source databases code and documentation such as mysql.
See [Studying MySQL, SQLite source code to learn about RDBMS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468751/studying-mysql-sqlite-source-code-to-learn-about-rdbms-implementation) for similar question.
See also
http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Design_of_Main_Memory_Database_System